# Pin dependencies for bdist wheels while keeping unpinned for development

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I intend to distribute my Python project as a bdist wheel with pinned dependency versions so that changes to upstream dependencies don't break my code. However, when someone installs a development version of my project, e.g. via `pip install -e`, I wish to pull in whatever the latest version of the dependencies are so that I can constantly test my code against them.

The dependencies are listed in `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=["numpy", "scipy", "matplotlib"],
)
```

I create the wheel from the project root (the one that contains `setup.py`) with:

```
pip wheel . --no-deps
```

The created wheel, when installed, will also install whatever the latest versions of Numpy, Scipy and Matplotlib are. The unzipped wheel's `METADATA` file (that pip uses to determine the project's dependencies when installing it) shows this situation:

```
...other metadata...
Requires-Dist: numpy
Requires-Dist: scipy
Requires-Dist: matplotlib
```

If I change `install_requires` in `setup.py` to set explicit versions for the dependencies (e.g. with `install_requires=["numpy==1.20.0", ...etc...]`), the created wheel's `METADATA` instead lists:

```
...other metadata...
Requires-Dist: numpy (==1.20.0)
...other dependencies...
```

This tells `pip` on the end user's machine to grab Numpy 1.20.0. This is what I want for the wheel, but then whenever someone runs `pip install -e .` they also get these pinned versions.

Is there a way to specify "development" dependencies as opposed to "wheel" dependencies programmatically? Or am I stuck telling people to manually run a `pip install -r unpinned-requirements.txt` and `pip install -e . --no-deps`?

Answer (score 0):

*Update:*

So basically what you want to do is to pin the requirements in the wheel, but not in the development environment.

#### Pinning the requirements in `setup.py`:

```py
import sys
import subprocess
from packaging.requirements import InvalidRequirement, Requirement

if 'bdist_wheel' in sys.argv:  # building the wheel

    if your_environment_is_clean:  # e.g. in a build pipeline
        # get requirements from pip freeze
        # NOTE: this also pins all sub-requirements

        res = subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "freeze"], check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
        requirements = res.stdout.split('\n')

    elif you_want_to_pin_your_requirements_here:
        requirements = [
            "numpy==1.20.0",  # pinned versions for wheel
            # ...
        ]

    else:
        # load pinned requirements from file

        with open("requirements.txt") as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
        
        requirements = []
        for line in lines:
            try:  
                # check if lines are valid requirements
                req = Requirement(line)
                requirements.append(str(req))
            except InvalidRequirement:
                pass
else:
    # not building a wheel

    requirements = [
        "numpy",  # unpinned versions for development
        # ...
    ]

setuptools.setup(
    install_requires=requirements,
    # ...
)
```

---

#### Manually adjust wheel after build:

You could pin the versions in the wheel only. I don't know if any tool exists for that, but you can do it manually:

```
[pip install wheel]
pip wheel --no-deps [-e] .
wheel unpack <package>-<spec>.whl
```

Pin the versions in `package-<version>/<package>-<spec>/METADATA` and repack the wheel:

```
wheel pack <package>
```

Then deploy the wheel.